# What did I miss? No output is shown

Tags: javascript, java

```html
//Q1.7
class Toing {

  public static void main(String [] args){
    
  }
    public int distance(int sq1,int sq2){
     int x1 = sq1%8;
     int y1 = sq1/8;
     int x2 = sq2%8;
     int y2 = sq2/8;
     double a = Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1));
    
     if(a % Math.sqrt(2) >= 1.41 && a % Math.sqrt(2) <= 1.42){
       return (int) (Math.round(a/Math.sqrt(2)));
     }
     else if(sq2 == sq1){
       return 0;
     }
     else {
       return (int)a;
     }
   }
  //Q1.8
    public boolean sameColumn(int sq1,int sq2) {
      return ((sq2 - sq1) % 8 == 0);
    }
 }
```

[image]

Hello, can someone help me if there's anything that I miss while doing these questions as when I run the command, it only shows "Run Toing". Is it suppose to show the answer or we just need to have the code only? As this question is about moving etc for example in

Q.1.7) the distance(0,63)=>6 . Should my output when I run the command show 6? 
Q.1.8) sameColumn(10,12)=>true. Should my output when I run the command show true?

If yes, what do I miss writing it down on my commands as I cant think anymore as I wrote too many java thing today.. just want to check with you guys if anyone can help as I don't have someone that know java.. Thank you

Comment: Javascript != Java.

Comment: Javascript !== Java either

Comment: Use the Developer Tools in Chrome.  It has a nice JS debugger.

Answer (score 0):

To get out put you need to run the program. Right now `main` is empty and does nothing. 
Here is an example of using `Toing` object:

```
public static void main(String [] args){

  //create a Toing object
  Toing t = new Toing();
  //use it to calculate distance
  int distance = t.distance(500,1200);
  System.out.println("distance = "+ distance);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your main method is empty therefore the app is good design but doing nothing..

if you want to see some output in the console use System.out.println() method

in your case you need an instance of the class Toing

so do this:

```
public static void main(String [] args){

  Toing myToingInstance = new Toing();

  int distance = myToingInstance.distance(0,63);
  System.out.println(" Tchebychev distance from 0 to 63 is: "+ distance);
}
```